# If $\sum_j a_j b_j \ge \sum c_j b_j$, then $a_j \ge c_j$.

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, optimization, summation

If $\sum_j a_j b_j \ge \sum c_j b_j$, then $a_j \ge c_j$?

If so, why?

If not, what are some sufficient or necessary conditions to make it true? I think $b_j \ge 0$ is a sufficient condition.

---

Context: This comes from an introduction to Duality in Operational Research/Linear Programming, where I think $b_j \ge 0$ in order to have feasibility.

---

[image]

---

From Chapter 2 [here](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21ABIU1apSS8r3CbA&id=5EA51B764D593198%212679&cid=5EA51B764D593198).

Comment: $b_j\geq 0$ for all $j$ is not enough.  Take $b_j=0$ for all $j$: then the inequality $0 \geq 0$ tells you *nothing* about $(a_j)_j$ and $(c_j)_j$.

Comment: $b_j \ge 0$ for all j and then $b_k > 0$ for some k ?

Comment: The only thing you can deduce from that is that $a_j$ is bigger than $c_j$ for SOME value of $j$. And indeed, there are examples where only one such $j$ exists.

Answer (score 3):

**First observation:** $b_j\geq 0$ for all $j$ is not enough.  Take $b_j=0$ for all $j$: then the inequality $0 \geq 0$ tells you *nothing* about $(a_j)_j$ and $(c_j)_j$.

**Second observation:** *nothing* (in terms of conditions on $(b_j)_j$), really, is enough. Indeed, you can rewrite your original inequality as
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n (a_j-c_j)b_j \geq 0
$$
or equivalently 
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n d_j b_j \geq 0
$$
setting $d_j\stackrel{\rm def}{=} a_j-c_j$ for all $1\leq j\leq n$. Your question is then "under what assumption(s) on $(b_j)_j$ does it imply $d_j \geq 0$ for all $j$?"

But the above is just again equivalent to saying $\langle \vec{d}, \vec{b}\rangle \geq 0$ for two $n$-dimensional vectors $\vec{d}, \vec{b}$. And the inequality does not actually say **anything** -- it is for instance satisfied, with equality, for any $\vec{d}$ orthogonal to $\vec{b}$... and if $\vec{d}$ satisfies $\langle \vec{d}, \vec{b}\rangle = 0$, so does $-\vec{d}$.

Comment: $b_j \ge 0$ for all j and then $b_k > 0$ for some k ?

Comment: No, read my answer. For instance, in two dimensions (this generalizes): take $b_1=b_2=1$, $a_1=-a_2=1$, $c_1=-c_2=-1$.

Answer (score 2):

This may seem logical since

$$\sum a_jb_j\geq \sum c_jb_j\rightarrow \sum a_jb_j- \sum c_jb_j\geq 0\rightarrow \sum (a_j-c_j)b_j\geq 0$$

But it is easy to construct a counter-example. Let $b_1=1$ and $b_2=100$. Then $a_1=1$, $a_2=2$ and $c_1=2$ and $c_2=1$ do not satisfy $a_j\geq c_j$, but satisfy $\sum a_jb_j\geq \sum c_jb_j$:

$$
\begin{align}
\sum a_jb_j&=1+2\cdot 100=201\\
\sum c_jb_j&=2+1\cdot 100=102\\
\end{align}
$$